# Does the target of dissonant whisper still use its reaction if it cannot move?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, reactions

Assume that the target of [*dissonant whispers*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dissonant-whispers) failed its Wisdom saving throw and that it cannot move.

I don't think that the reason the target cannot move is relevant, but for example it might have a condition that reduces its speed to 0 (such as grappled), or it might be surrounded by "obviously dangerous ground".

Does the target use its reaction to move 0 feet?
Or does it not use its reaction because it cannot move?
Or something else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The target still uses its reaction.

Dissonant Whispers states:

> On a failed save, it [...] must immediately use its reaction, if available, **to move as far as its speed allows** away from you.

If the creature's speed only allows it to move 0 feet away from you then that's as far as it moves, but it does still use its reaction.

Comment: perhaps "must immediately use it's reaction" is the pertinent info to answer the OP's question. Otherwise excellent answer. +1